# How to configure ISP neutral DNS on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, dns, privacy

I learned recently that for privacy reasons it is wise to replace the AUTO configured DNS on my iPhone.

I wanted to know how exactly one could do that?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the video on this link.

https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/setting-up-1.1.1.1/iphone/